Reverse question of superposition of waves
This is a soft question.
Consider two Gaussian like pulse waves with different heights, means and variances, and there is an overlap between them. By the principle of superposition, they form a new pattern as a whole. What I get is the whole pattern and I want to get the approx/accurate patterns of the two separate pulse waves, which is the reverse process of superposition. Are there any tools to solve problems like this one?
In reality, there is one more difficulty: I can only get the y value at specific x's for the resolution. Therefore, I cannot expect to use "infinitesimals" methods to solve the problem.

wouldn't that be just the Fourier transform?

@paulina But I still want to conserve the Gaussian-like pattern, not the sinusoidal one.

the Fourier transform of a Gaussian should just be another Gaussian.
